# How to force postgres to use columns order from csv when dumping/restore data?

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-copy

I dump my table data:

```
COPY( SELECT * FROM tariff_details ) TO STDOUT WITH( FORMAT CSV, HEADER )
```

The data:

```
id,tariff_id,name,price,option,periodic,value,sorder
17,1,Setup fee,5.000000000000000000,,f,,0
```

When I restore the data:

```
COPY tariff_details FROM STDIN WITH( FORMAT CSV, HEADER )
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "periodic" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (17, 1, Setup fee, 5.000000000000000000, null, f, null, 0).
CONTEXT:  COPY tariff_details, line 2: "17,1,Setup fee,5.000000000000000000,,f,,0"
```

The table in database is defined as next:

```
  Column   |         Type          |                          Modifiers                          
-----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer               | not null default nextval('tariff_details_id_seq'::regclass)
 tariff_id | integer               | not null
 name      | character varying(64) | not null
 price     | tmoney                | not null
 periodic  | boolean               | not null default false
 option    | character varying(16) | 
 value     | text                  | 
 sorder    | integer               | not null default 0
```

As you can see the fields `option` and `periodic` are flipped.

[Postgres documentation says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html):

> HEADER
>
> Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names of each column in the file. On output, the first line contains the column names from the table, and on input, **the first line is ignored**. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.

How to to tell postgres to use columns order from CSV file?
Is it possible?

**UPD**

As work around I use: `line=$$(head -n 1 ${APP_ROOT}/db/${TABLE}.dump.csv)`

```
dbrestoretable: export PGPASSWORD =  ${DB_PASS}
dbrestoretable:
    line=$$(head -n 1 ${APP_ROOT}/db/${TABLE}.dump.csv)
    @cat ${APP_ROOT}/db/${TABLE}.dump.csv | \
        psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p ${DB_PORT} -U ${DB_USER} ${DB_NAME} -c \
            "BEGIN;COPY ${TABLE}($$line) FROM STDIN WITH( FORMAT CSV, HEADER );COMMIT;"  ||:
```

Comment: `COPY tariff_details (list,of,your,columns,here,in,order) FROM STDIN WITH( FORMAT CSV, HEADER )` And the same can be done for`COPY ...TO...;`

Comment: @wildplasser: No. This is makefile. As parameter it get table name. We should not require columns from user.

Comment: There is no Makefile and no user in your question. The bad news is: there is no *order* in the columns if you use `SELECT *`

Comment: RE(UPD) you could try to replace `\t` in $$line by `,` , using sed or tr.

Comment: On second thought: you already have commas.

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify ***target*** column names in [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

```
COPY tariff_details(id,tariff_id,name,option,price,periodic,value,sorder)
FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

(I flipped `option` and `periodic`.)

Aside: `SELECT * FROM tbl` *does* return columns in deterministic order - as  defined in [`pg_attribute.attnum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html). So something had have changed in your DB between dump and restore.

Comment: As you can see I did this: `COPY ${TABLE}($$line) FROM STDIN`

Answer (score 0):

As work around I use: `columns=$$(head -n 1 ${APP_ROOT}/db/${TABLE}.dump.csv)`

```
dbrestoretable: export PGPASSWORD =  ${DB_PASS}
dbrestoretable:
    columns=$$(head -n 1 ${APP_ROOT}/db/${TABLE}.dump.csv)
    @cat ${APP_ROOT}/db/${TABLE}.dump.csv | \
        psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p ${DB_PORT} -U ${DB_USER} ${DB_NAME} -c \
            "BEGIN;COPY ${TABLE}($$columns) FROM STDIN WITH( FORMAT CSV, HEADER );COMMIT;"  ||:
```